# issue in get attribute name from xml file in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Attribute]

I tried to get attribute of Chandru element but it showing the exception like "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

exactly  i have to get value  sst5038 from the above  xml file.

Here the code  what i wrote

```
public partial class XML_3 : Window
{
    public XML_3()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("D:/student_2.xml");

        XmlNodeList student_list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Student");

        foreach (XmlNode node in student_list)
        {
            XmlElement student = (XmlElement)node;

            string sname = student.GetElementsByTagName("Chandru")[0].InnerText;

            string fname = student.GetElementsByTagName("FName")[0].InnerText;

            string id = student.Attributes["ID"].InnerText;

            Window.Content = sname + fname + id;
        }
    }
}
```

please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be
for first student

```
string id = student.GetElementsByTagName("Chandru")[0].Attributes["ID"].InnerText;
```

and
for second student

```
string id = student.GetElementsByTagName("Guna")[0].Attributes["ID"].InnerText;
```